# How to Scope css to a div without placing scoped on the style tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm in desperate need of scoping my css to a specific div.

What I want, is for my styles within a certain div to only affect anything within that div, and nothing outside it.

Example:

```
        <style>
            p {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="global">
            <p>I am styled by the global styling!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="scoped">
            <style>
                p{
                    color: blue;
                    background: green;
                }
            </style>
            <p>These scoped styles do not affect the global styles</p>
        </div>
```

I know about placing scoped on the style tag, but the browser support is no where near close to practical use.

Because of that, I'm wondering if there is some way to achieve this by other means, like JavaScript?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm not in search for scoping it by placing a class before it, like .scoped p.
I need it to be dynamic, and i can't place .scoped in front of all the tags.

Comment: why didn't you use `.scoped p{ color:blue; background:green}` and `global p{ color:red;}`

Comment: I explained my self poorly. Please see edit

Comment: Using JS, the style will be inline and overriding CSS so that'll work. It's actually quite easy with jQuery : `$('.scoped p').css({... bunch of properties ...});`

Answer (score 1):

How about using CSS classes? For example:

```
/* This only applies to p inside div with class 'global' */
div.global p {
    color: red;
}

/* This only applies to p inside div with class 'scoped' */
div.scoped p{
    color: blue;
    background: green;
}
```

If you want all p to have global style and only scoped to have separate style, leave the p rule as it is and create scoped rule:

```
/* This rule applies to all p elements */
p {
    color: red;
}

/* This style overrides style of p inside div with class 'scoped' */
div.scoped p{
    color: blue;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: @user3385205 It is still clear what you are trying to achieve, Are you loading these `p` elements dynamically and you want them to have their own style? If so, why not use `style="color: blue; background: green"` on `p` element?

Comment: No. I need to be able to prevent styling from global elements within my child element.

If i style ".sidebar", it should only style within that div.

Answer (score 0):

select every class separately:

```
.global p {
    color: red;
}

.scoped p{
    color: blue;
    background: green;
}
```